# Cronjobs stay on pending

Tags: magento2, magento-cron, cronjobs

I put my cronjobs to every minute, but i think there is still someting wrong. I still have some cronjobs who stay's on pending...
[image]

My pending cronjobs:
[image]

I migrate my Magento from 1.7 to 2.3

Comment: which magneto version you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.2.5 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding if time "executed" (right column) is in the past it must be either "missed" or "success". It can remain pending only if crontab does not run

Comment: I checked the cronjobs again, and even still a lot of cronjobs get the status "missed".

Comment: did you run cron twice? I mean the command?

Comment: Just run the command once